# what do _safe_repr and pformat in "python -m pprint" mean?

Tags: python, linux, shell, stdout

Are they related to the python interpreter or the stdout of linux distro
and please i want an explanation of process flow if you interested to this

```
$type cd | python -m pprint 

_safe_repr: 4.332890303998283
pformat: 9.275150911998935
```

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question is narrow, specific, and related to a problem you actually face in the course of software development. Part of "narrow" means that it should be amenable to a canonical answer. "An explanation of process flow" isn't specific at all -- someone writing an explanation could go infinitely deep into how far they go into details.

Comment: (BTW, your code will have the exact same output without `type cd |` at the front; why is that there?)

Comment: `type cd |` was there because i wanted to pass it's output  as an argument to the python **pprint** module or i thought it was the right way to do so. But i didn't expect an output, and i was so curious why this got printed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `pprint.py`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _perfcheck()
```

...which runs:

```
def _perfcheck(object=None):
    import time
    if object is None:
        object = [("string", (1, 2), [3, 4], {5: 6, 7: 8})] * 100000
    p = PrettyPrinter()
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    _safe_repr(object, {}, None, 0)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    p.pformat(object)
    t3 = time.perf_counter()
    print("_safe_repr:", t2 - t1)
    print("pformat:", t3 - t2)
```

Thus, when you run `python -m pprint` (invoking the pprint module as `__main__`), the performance of `_safe_repr()` (wrapped and documented for external consumption as [`saferepr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.saferepr)) and the performance of [`pformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat) are being compared for the sample object created by `[("string", (1, 2), [3, 4], {5: 6, 7: 8})] * 100000`.

---

To quote the documentation distinguishing between the meaning and purpose of these two functions:

> `pformat()`
> Format a Python object into a pretty-printed representation.
>
> `saferepr()`
> Generate a 'standard' repr()-like value, but protect against recursive
> data structures.